# Active Record Sort by 2 conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord

How can I sort by number first and further sort same number names by alphabet?

Example:

```
Score | Name
-----------
12     John
11     Paul
10     Dave
9      Adam
9      Ben
9      David
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the SQL syntax for ordering by multiple columns:

```
order by Score, Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from Table Order by Score , Name
```